# Send data to php using pure javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to send an object of javascript to php file for processing using AJAX.
**JAVASCRIPT**

```
let form_data =  {"resend_OTP":true,"option":"second"}
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest');
/* below line of code must be there for POST requests.*/
xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(form_data));
```

**PHP**

```
$args = $_POST;
print_r($args); //output as array given below 
foreach ($args as $key => $value) {
  print_r(json_decode($key)); //output as object given below
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [{"resend_OTP":true,"option":"second"}] => 
)

stdClass Object
(
    [resend_OTP] => 1
    [option] => second
)
```

It gives the output as I want. But I need to use foreach loop in PHP to get correct output by usnig json_decode.
My question is that -
Whatever I sent to php it get stored as array key (see below).

```
Array
(
    [{"resend_OTP":true,"option":"second"}] => 
)
```

I want to get it as -

```
key : value
```